# Synchronized , передача ссылки на массив

Tags: java, многопоточность, arraylist, synchronized

У меня есть объект

```
public class Detail {
    public int number;
    volatile public boolean status;
    Detail (int i)
    {
        this.number = i;
        this.status = false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "["+this.number+"] take = "+this.status;
    }
}
```

и я создаю массив объектов

```
ArrayList<Detail> details = new ArrayList<Detail>(6);
for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
{
    details.add(new Detail(i));
}
```

у меня существует несколько потоков которые будут юзать эти объекты. Мне надо синхронизировать их доступ к объекту, так как одной деталью два сразу пользоваться не смогут. Если я буду передавать ссылку на этот Лист, то они будут в общем иметь доступ по очереди к массиву или к каждому объекту будет своя очередь?

П.с есть код потоков которые это все используют, кода много, если надо то добавлю.

Comment: В массив добавляются еще элементы или это конечный размер?

Comment: конечный, 6 элементов и 6 потоков, подобие задачи об обедающих философах

Comment: Что значит "по очереди к массиву"? все зависит от того как вы синхронизацию сделаете. Если тупо обернете коллекцию в Collections.synchronizedCollection то да, одновременный доступ будет к списку только у одного потока. Если же повесить лок на объект то очередь будет уже у объекта. Сейчас в вашем коде нет никакой синхронизации.

Comment: Знаю что нет никакой синхронизации. То есть мне надо вешать лок на объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я как понимаю, у вас в поле `status` определяется используется объект или нет. Если поменять его тип на `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean` то на основе его значения, можно обеспечить синхронизацию потоков.

Примерно так:

```
    //неизменяемый список из 6 деталей
    final List<Detail> details = Collections
            .unmodifiableList(
                    //берем стрим из последовательности чисел
                    //от 0 до 6. Преобразуем числа в детали
                    //собираем все это в список
                    IntStream
                            .range(0, 6)
                            .mapToObj(Detail::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );


    final int threadCount = 10;
    //создаем threadpool из 10 потоков
    ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        //создаем задачи и отпраляем их на выполнение
        executors.execute(() -> {
            //пытаемся в каждом потоке забрать деталь 10_000 раз
            for (int j = 0; j < 10_000; j++)
                //бежим по списку и сравниваем 
                //если у детали статус false то выставляем ей true
                //и спим 100 милисекунд
                for (Detail detail : details)
                    if (detail.status.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                        System.out.println(detail);
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //возвращаем статус в false
                        detail.status.set(false);
                    }
        });
```

Comment: Так что же лучше лочить объект или хитро-мудро как вы сделали?Я вообще не понял что происходит в вашем коде?

Comment: все зависит от того, что вам нужно. Как по мне, CAS выглядит более предпочтительным.

Comment: Извините, а можно этот же код но с комментариями, а то я как впервые код программы увидел....

Comment: Ещё глупый вопросик, вы говорили привести к atomic boolean где конкретно происходит магия преобразования детали ? Мы при создании детали делаем её синхронизированной или в классе деталь?Спасибо.

Comment: volatile public boolean status -> public final AtomicBoolean status = new AtomicBoolean();